# Opencart and VQmod issue with modifying files

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I need help with using VQmod, if anyone has any experience with, I'd appreciate any help. I went over the VQmod docs, but might've missed something. I am trying to add a new tab to the Opencart new product form(product_form.tpl), vqmod adds the code, but doesn't put it in the right place:

Modification:

```
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <a href="#tab-design"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <a href="#tab-pins"><?php echo $tab_pins; ?></a>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

Modified code, before modification:

```
    <div id="tabs" class="htabs">

        <a href="#tab-general"><?php echo $tab_general; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-data"><?php echo $tab_data; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-links"><?php echo $tab_links; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-option"><?php echo $tab_option; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-discount"><?php echo $tab_discount; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-special"><?php echo $tab_special; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-image"><?php echo $tab_image; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-reward"><?php echo $tab_reward; ?></a>
        <a href="#tab-design"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a>

</div>
```

After modification:

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
<a class="selected" href="#tab-general" style="display: inline;">General</a>
<a href="#tab-data" style="display: inline;">Data</a>
<a href="#tab-links" style="display: inline;">Links</a>
<a href="#tab-attribute" style="display: inline;">Attribute</a>
<a href="#tab-option" style="display: inline;">Option</a>
<a href="#tab-discount" style="display: inline;">Discount</a>
<a href="#tab-special" style="display: inline;">Special</a>
<a href="#tab-image" style="display: inline;">Image</a>
<a href="#tab-reward" style="display: inline;">Reward Points</a>
<a href="#tab-design" style="display: inline;">Design</a>
</div>
<a href="#tab-pins">Pin Numbers</a>
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks, Lea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <a href="#tab-design"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[<a href="#tab-design"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a><a href="#tab-pins"><?php echo $tab_pins; ?></a>]]></add>
        </operation>
</file>
```

That should resolve it. You should always use the `replace` over `after` for adding tabs